# maven: Removing format file extension from created assembly

Tags: file, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I've got a Maven2 project, where I use assembly plugin. Everything would be just fine if created assembly file name wouldn't ended with format extension (ex. ".zip"). I specified in plugin configuration a fileName parameter and setted appendAssemblyId to false. I have already spent few hours on that problem... Any idea?

Comment: @starblue `[assembly]` IS a Maven concept, `[assemblies]` is not. Those restrictions you put on tags (which are for **sets**) are tiring.

Comment: Here is a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741555/maven-rename-a-file-after-everything-else-finishes

Answer (score -1):

My answer is a bit of a non-answer - don't remove the format extension.  If you are using a specific `<format>` in your assembly descriptor to produce an artifact (zip, tar.gz, etc.) there is exists no good reason to remove the extension from the file. If I'm a user of your software and download this binary, I don't want to have to guess as to what the packaging type is, I should be able to tell just by looking at the filename.

FWIW, setting appendAssemblyId to false means that the `<id>` of your assembly descriptor will not be included in your file name.

Now, if you really are dead set on making this a pain for you and everyone else, what you probably want to do (as with most nonsensical things people want to make maven do) is to either use the [antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to rename the generated file during your maven invocation, or just simply run a shell script to rename it after your maven process has finished.

Comment: Well... I need to remove ".zip" from a file because I'm developing a plugin to some software, and it needs a plugin with specific extension. This plugin is basically a ZIP archive with appropriate structure.

Comment: I really need to invoke mvn assembly:assembly separately because I don't want to build assembly during every compile process. I was trying to use Exec Plugin, but Assembly plugin  creates it's own building process with only package phase and if I was trying to bind renaming command with package phase then whole build process was failing everytime because reanming was executed before creating assembly