# Maven rename a file after everything else finishes

Tags: maven, ant

I have a project which I need to rename the final output file generated by the `Maven Assembly Plugin` after everything else finishes (in the compiling/building/assembly process).

The `Maven Assembly Plugin` is generating a final `.zip` file, based on the project's name, and I need to rename this completely to `final-version.oxt`. I'm trying to use the `maven-antrun-plugin` to rename it, as pointed by other similar questions here, but no luck (I've never used Maven or Ant before, so maybe I'm missing something).

This is the `<build>` section of the project's `pom.xml`. The rename part seems to be completely ignored, since no file is generated in my `home` folder.

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/ooo-jar.xml</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/ooo.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>

                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <copy file="${project.build.directory}/target/libreofficeplugin-ooo.zip"
                             tofile="/home/brunofinger/final-version.oxt" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A few modifications made it work, probably the `phase` was wrong, but using `<phase>install</phase>` seems to make it work:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>

                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <copy file="${project.build.directory}/libreofficeplugin-ooo.zip" tofile="${project.build.directory}/final-version.oxt" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: for package phase and java 8, change <target> to <tasks>

Answer (score 12):

This question is nearly an year old, but in case anyone else is facing similar issue, here is an alternate solution.

If you are looking for a more mavenish way of doing it,you can use

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>rename-file</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>rename</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sourceFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/libreofficeplugin-ooo.zip</sourceFile>
          <destinationFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/final-version.oxt</destinationFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

and in case you want to copy instead of rename, use the [copy](https://coderplus.github.io/copy-rename-maven-plugin/copy-mojo.html) goal instead of the [rename](https://coderplus.github.io/copy-rename-maven-plugin/rename-mojo.html) goal.

Comment: Cant seem to be able to skip the execution of this plugin with a profile. Do you know how to get this done?

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to use antrun to rename the output file. Just use the tag finalName of the assembly plugin to rename the output file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>assembly</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>attached</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <archive>
               <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
            </archive>
            <descriptors>
               <descriptor>src/main/assembly/ooo-jar.xml</descriptor>
               <descriptor>src/main/assembly/ooo.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
            <finalName>final-version.oxt</finalName>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It didn't work, it's still attaching the `.zip` extension to the end of the file, generating a file named `final-version.oxt.zip`. I need to get rid of the `.zip`.

Comment: You are right. The finalName renames only the name of the file, not the extension.

Comment: The `finalName` configuration element no longer exists in maven-assembly-plugin 3.0.0.

Comment: `finalName` still exists but has been moved out of the plugin section into the `build` section of the config. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14490656/286685).

Comment: `finalName` renames all JARs, not just the assembled JAR. That's probably because it changes the actual POM value instead of keeping it isolated with assembly. Maybe that's why it was removed from documentation.

Comment: `finalName` renames all JARs, not just the assembled JAR. That's probably because it changes the actual POM value instead of keeping it isolated with assembly. Maybe that's why it was removed from documentation.