# How to use different application.conf per environment in Akka-Http?

Tags: scala, configuration, akka, akka-http

I am new in Akka and want to set up different `application.conf` files per environment (test, staging, prod, etc.).

I read the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.6/scala/general/configuration.html) from Akka but I couldn't find a way to do it.

May you know any proper way to have multiple configuration files?

Answer (score 3):

Akka uses the [Typesafe Config Library](https://github.com/lightbend/config).

The convenience method ConfigFactory.load() loads the following (first-listed are higher priority):

1. system properties
2. application.conf (all resources on classpath with this name)
3. application.json (all resources on classpath with this name)
4. application.properties (all resources on classpath with this name)
5. reference.conf (all resources on classpath with this name)

So we usually create an application.conf file in /resources folder.

For different environments, we can create environment specific files like

1. development.conf
2. production.conf

Using [includes](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#includes), include application.conf at the beginning and specify environment specific configurations which will override the application.conf.

To use a specific environment force a different config source (e.g. from command line -Dconfig.resource=environment.conf)

Start your application using below command:

**$ sbt run -Dconfig.resource=development.conf**

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple ways to do it.

1. Add tags with in a file itself like

> prod-config : {   YOUR_CONFIGURATION_FOR_PROD }
>
> test-config : { YOUR_CONFIGURATION_TEST_ENV }
>
> and so-on

2. Make separate files for the each environment and rename it once after deploying them to specific environment. Say from `application-prod.conf` to `application.conf`

Comment: In both of suggestions, how you can choose different file per environment?

Comment: In 1st approach you have only one file which have properties per environment separated by tags based on environment. In 2nd approach you can ask build tool to rename (say for Maven https://stackoverflow.com/a/26639059/3595618) using a custom property(https://stackoverflow.com/a/24206194/3595618).

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is have a single variable in application.conf which would be "confFile", based on an actual env like

```
confFile=${?CONF_FILE_NAME}
```

Then in your code, you load the correspondind file like this

```
val configFile = ConfigFactory.load().getString("confFile")
val appConf = ConfigFactory.load(configFile)
```

Comment: This config file should be `.conf`, `.properties` or something else?

Comment: Both are possible. If I'm not mistaken, the typesafe config factory will look for .conf, .properties and .json extensions

Answer (score 0):

The options for this aren't so much related to Akka as it is to the config library. Akka uses the default config resolution unless you give it a `Config` instance.

With no specific user code to manually select a specific file you have a few options. I think the most useful are the system properties `config.resource` to choose a file on the class path (inside the app jar for example), `config.file` to use a file from the file system.

Of course you may still have reasons to write your own code to select files as the other answers suggested.

More details in the config library docs: https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior