# How to stop maven from output "[WARNING] Configuration option 'appendAssemblyId' is set to false."?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a maven project generating a jar and not appending maven-assembly-plugin's appendAssemblyId.

How can I get maven to stop issuing the warning: "Configuration option 'appendAssemblyId' is set to false." ?

**EDIT:** I was asked to include the pom file, which I'm not permitted to do. I'm including the maven-assembly-plugin block which causes the error.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>some.company.hello</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <!-- prevent appending <descriptorRef> "jar-with-dependencies" to final jar name -->
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <!-- For inheritance merges -->
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
      <phase>package</phase> 
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please show your pom file?

Comment: This is simple not your pom file. This is only the maven-assembly-plugin configuration part...does not help here...You can of course add the pom file where groupId/artifactId etc. are replaced with "XX" etc. The question is why you have defined the `<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>` which does usually not makes sense.. ?

Comment: @ khmarbaise Thanks for your help..<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId> "is" the source of the warning.  Removing the tag or changing the value from "false" to "true" negates the warning, but appends "jar-with-dependencies" to the jar.   I was hoping someone has already solved this issue. I may have to look at the sources find if it's possible to suppress warnings. I used  maven-assembly-plugin due to other warning from shade. I'd write a suppress warning plugin if someone else could maintain it.

Comment: This is not an issue it's intentional to have this warning if you have set it to false. If you are using maven-shade-plugin you don't need to use maven-assembly-plugin...the question is: what kind of warnings did you had there ? A suppress warning plugin is simply the wrong way cause you seemed to misunderstand some of the use cases and intentions of the plugins ...

Comment: @ khmarbaise...  as said previously I moved away from maven-shade-plugin and used maven-assembly-plugin instead.  "A suppress warning plugin is simply the wrong way cause you seemed to misunderstand some of the use cases and intentions of the plugins"  I fully understand the use cases and intention of the plugin, I just don't like the warning and frankly find it insulting. If I chose to remove the assembly-id, I know I'm doing it and don't need to be second guessed.

Comment: It is a reasonable requirement to create the final jar file that you can specify the name, in this case without the '-jar-with-dependencies' part. It is an old question now. I hope somebody have found a proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38484021/950837) explains the technical details, but I think the key is the phrase that you mentioned in your question.

> I have a maven project generating a jar and not appending maven-assembly-plugin's appendAssemblyId.

If I'm understanding correctly, I take this to mean that in your pom file, you have an entry that says

```xml
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

What this does is create a jar file that competes with the output of the maven-assembly-plugin, and maven-assembly-plugin wins out, resulting in only one jar file. In fact, if you were to set `appendAssemblyId` back to `true`, you will get two files in the output directory - `<artifact>.jar` and `<artifact>-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

So, first, you should remove the `<packaging>` tag I mentioned above, and add the following to the `<executions>` section of your pom file so that there won't be two conflicting/competing jar files (and the warning will go away):

```xml
<execution>
    <id>default-jar</id>
    <phase>none</phase>
</execution>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, I wanted the standard-named jar (without the ugly "jar-with-dependencies" appendix) to be standalone, that is with all dependencies included.

However, as the OP noticed: `<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>` does the job, but also issues a build warning. For me this is an issue, because I have a strict pipeline where the build should fail on warnings. And I want to keep it this way.

The solution was use `<appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>`, but then rename the generated jar file in a subsequent step (So the jar-with-dependencies one overwrites the default jar).

Namely, I used the [`copy-rename-maven-plugin`](https://coderplus.github.io/copy-rename-maven-plugin/), to get the job done:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>rename-file</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>rename</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/${build.name}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</sourceFile>
                            <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/${build.name}.jar</destinationFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Effect: No more warnings, the generated jar has the dependencies included, but comes without the ugly filename appendix.

For the credits, this snippet was inspired [by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26639059/13805480). I changed the maven phase though, and switched for a variable-based approach, to keep it generic. You'll need to define the `build.name`, in your project `properties`, e.g. like so:

```xml
    <properties>
        <build.name>my-funny-program-name-here</build.name>
    </properties>
```